# Apk with only arm64-v8a binaries will not install

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm64

I have an app that embeds a native build of v8 plus some extensions through cmake. Up to now it was compiled for x86 and armv7 and would then strip all the shared libs for other architectures dropped in by Crashlytics.

I've added a build for arm64-v8a now and cannot get a device or emulator to actually execute the 64 bit code. An apk containing only armv8 libs will not install:

```
# unzip -v app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk |grep lib
13863240  Defl:N  4904804  65% 00-00-1980 00:00 7b2e5eef  lib/arm64-v8a/libbgjs.so
   13648  Defl:N     4168  70% 00-00-1980 00:00 2b60e8f9  lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics-envelope.so
  530392  Defl:N   202134  62% 00-00-1980 00:00 2d08ed8e  lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics.so
  149248  Defl:N    59350  60% 00-00-1980 00:00 957899e1  lib/arm64-v8a/libmyrmecophaga.so
  116416  Defl:N    51520  56% 00-00-1980 00:00 73a9138b  lib/arm64-v8a/libunwind-crashlytics.so

# adb install app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk 
Failed to install app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
# adb logcat
09-20 11:40:09.716 3640-3764/? W/NativeHelper: Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-113]
09-20 11:40:09.716 3640-3764/? E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session 1828012220 failed: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
```

If I use a "fat" apk with both armv7 and arm64-v8a then it will default to using the armv7 .so.

Any help would be apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the Android bug tracker I found the solution. The problem was that I was using renderscript version 19, which automatically created .bc files, which in turn made the package manager ignore the arm64 libs. Upping that to 21 and enabling renderscript compat made it work.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37134362